# exception when running play v2 application

Tags: java, playframework-2.3

I am trying to launch a play v2 app (previously set up by another developer) but I am getting the following error message when I run activator run (the application itself is in Java):

```
ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error in custom provider, akka.ConfigurationException: Type [akka.dispatch.BoundedControlAwareMessageQueueSemantics] specified as akka.actor.mailbox.requirement [akka.actor.mailbox.bounded-control-aware-queue-based] in config can't be loaded due to [akka.dispatch.BoundedControlAwareMessageQueueSemantics]
  while locating play.api.libs.concurrent.ActorSystemProvider
  while locating akka.actor.ActorSystem
    for parameter 6 at play.api.DefaultApplication.<init>(Application.scala:241)
  at play.api.DefaultApplication.class(Application.scala:241)
  while locating play.api.DefaultApplication
  while locating play.api.Application

1 error

No source available, here is the exception stack trace:
         com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1025)
         com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1051)
         play.api.inject.guice.GuiceInjector.instanceOf(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:321)
         play.api.inject.guice.GuiceInjector.instanceOf(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:316)
         play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder.build(GuiceApplicationBuilder.scala:93)
         play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationLoader.load(GuiceApplicationLoader.scala:21)
         play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$2.apply(DevServerStart.scala:153)
         play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$2.apply(DevServerStart.scala:150)
         play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
         play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:150)
         play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:121)
         scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
         play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:121)
         play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:119)
         scala.util.Success.flatMap(Try.scala:231)
         play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:119)
         play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:111)
         scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
         scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
         java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1402)
         java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
         java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
         java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
         java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
```

Any ideas on what I might have misconfigured?  I can copy over the application.conf file as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by a misconfigured setup for swagger in order to generate API documentation.  Once I followed all the steps for setting up swagger and swagger-ui, the issue was resolved.  The stack trace itself was not useful in solving the issue.